# Creating executable which doesn't need any further installations to work on other computers?

Tags: c++, windows, executable

I am trying to make a simple desktop log app in which a list of pre-defined dates are shown which when selected, the relevant text appears in a description box and a button is updated so that when pressed it loads up the relevant PDF file for that date.

Now, I tried to do this on my own using visual c++ 2010 express and it all worked fine but when I sent it to others using windows they received an error message saying they need to download a later version of the .NET Framework.

Now I am back to the start and would like to know if there is any simple method of making such a GUI (such as visual C++) for which the executable file will work on any windows computer without needing any further installations.

Note: I have experience with C++ and Java programming and also I would prefer if the PDF's in my example were able to be merged within the executable, this would mean that I would only have to issue a single executable file to users rather than sending a folder full of PDF's with it (this did not work with visual c++ for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.100%29.aspx) deployments. A bit outdated, but will do the job.